# Python prebuilt

Tags: python

Some months ago I downloaded a Python package from which I could run Python (`./python`) directly without any installation. These days, I need to test several Python versions and I would like to test them without installing them. I can't find that package anymore, and the archive from the Python website gives configure et cmake files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414484/is-there-a-portable-python-interpreter-that-will-run-on-mac-os-x-10-6-from-a-usb and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259160/did-anyone-try-portable-python

Answer (score 1):

Is [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/) what you are referring to? On their [download page](http://www.portablepython.com/wiki/Download) there are links for versions 2.7 and 3.2 of Python as well as the older versions 2.5 and 2.6.

Comment: Well, I'm running Ubuntu distrib. :/

Comment: @NicoCati You should add that information to your question then. Maybe have a look at [Stackless Python](http://zope.stackless.com/Members/rmtew/News%20Archive/staticPython27) then.